# Can I remove the repeated row in Table1 & Table2?

Tags: sql

I used Left Join in this 
Table1 and Table2 has 1 row 
Table3 has 2 row . 
So the output is this 
 
|.....................Table1....................||........Table2..........||.........Table3..........||  
|**ItemName**...........|**Brand**............||**UOM** |**Qty**..|**Price**.||**UOM**.|**Qty**..|**Price**.|| 
|Short Bondpaper | HARDCOPY || PCS | 500 | 1100 || PCS | 100 | 1550||
|Short Bondpaper | HARDCOPY || PCS | 500 | 1100 || PCS | 100 | 2200||

Can I make it happen like this

|.....................Table1....................||........Table2..........||.........Table3..........||  
|**ItemName**...........|**Brand**............||**UOM** |**Qty**..|**Price**.||**UOM**.|**Qty**..|**Price**.|| 
|Short Bondpaper | HARDCOPY || PCS | 500 | 1100 || PCS | 100 | 1550||
|Short Bondpaper | HARDCOPY || -...... | 0.....| 0...... || PCS | 100 | 2200||

OR like this?

|.....................Table1....................||........Table2..........||.........Table3..........||  
|**ItemName**...........|**Brand**............||**UOM** |**Qty**..|**Price**.||**UOM**.|**Qty**..|**Price**.|| 
|Short Bondpaper | HARDCOPY || PCS | 500 | 1100 || PCS | 100 | 1550||
|NULL...................| NULL............||NULL|NULL|NULL|| PCS | 100 | 2200||

See Image

Comment: please specify the database

Comment: add your query and sample input data

Comment: This is formatting data for display, usually done on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Arrangement of join should be like below:

```
Select * From Table3 
Left outer join Table2 on table3.colname=table2.colname
Left outer join Table1 on table3.colname=table1.colname;
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no actual data and table structure it's not possible to provide actual query. Suggestion is to add a rank column in your query like

```
rank() over(partition by item_name, brand)
```

and set the desired columns to NULLs if rank > 1;